# Running Powershell "IEX" from C#

Tags: c#, powershell

I am trying to automate the running of a powershell script along with the running of other programs.

To run the powershell script manually, I would normally do this in a command prompt:

```
powershell "IEX (New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadString('http://serverurl/Script.ps1'); Invoke-Method"
```

I can't seem to replicate this in c# to save my life using built in "PowerShell" commands. I"d rather NOT have to use things like "Process", so any advice would be helpful.

Comment: Show us what you're already trying! If you're running this from C# then you've already got direct access to a `System.Net.WebClient` object, and you have access to the `.AddScript()` method on the PowerShell object, so you don't need `iex` within the PowerShell runspace..

Comment: All this is doing is executing [this C# statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw(v=vs.110).aspx). This will download it. Then use `PowerShellInstance.AddScript()` to execute it.

Comment: I was able to get it to work using the marked answer below.  Sorry, I'm not great with posting questions and whatnot yet, especially code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `System.Net.WebClient` is a .NET class, you don't need PowerShell to use it:

```
string script = (new System.Net.WebClient()).DownloadString('http://serverurl/Script.ps1');
```

To execute the script, use the [`System.Management.Automation.PowerShell`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.powershell(v=vs.85).aspx) class:

```
using System.Management.Automation;
// ...

using(PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
{
    ps.AddScript(script).AddScript("Invoke-Method");
    ps.Invoke();
}
```

Comment: Seems that doesn't work as intended.  It says the method I'm trying to invoke isn't a valid cmdlet/etc/etc.

Comment: What does `Script1.ps1` contain exactly?

Comment: A set of functions.  Almost like a module.  Like I said, it works with IEX syntax from command line.

Comment: After some more finessing, I was able to get this to work.  I had to add Runspaces.  I also captured the ps.Invoke(); into a collection of PSObjects and converted that to a string.